# Replace values by nearest value

Tags: qgis, vector, vector-grid

I have a vectorised meteorological dataset containing both precipitation and temperature for variables. This has been merged with a larger polygon however I have some `NULL` values in the field for temperature.

I could remove or replace these values and I choose to replace them, however how would I replace these values by the nearest datapoint to it?

for example:

```
temperature precipitation district
16              200         london
17              180         london
NULL            180         london
NULL            180         london
```

Let's say for the purpose of this context that these NULL values had `17` has the closest value-point to it hence replace it with those. Or looking at this as grid-cells, if I have a collection of grid-cells 4x4, and 1 of them has only null values within that cell, then pick the closest cell with the pixel containing values closest to it.

Comment: Can you please show us a bit of your data? It is not really clear to me what do you mean by *"the nearest datapoint to it"*: is it nearest in sense of location or in sense or the attribute table?

Comment: Have you had a look at the grass-vector-interpolation tools?